# Cannot stop bash to expand star (wildcard character) passed to app from shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

I have a shell bash script wich should pass the star ["*"] wildcard character to an application without using quotation marks.
I am reading since hours and always find to use "set -f" inside the callings shell script, but this does nothing. May be I've misunderstood something, but I do not see what.

I am writing a C# app with the mono framework and my call inside bash is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f
mono app.exe "$@"
```

My shell script named "runit" will be used like this:

> runit *

Can someone probably shed some light on this?
I even tried to output the active shell options from this script, but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
#!/bin/bash
set -f
mono app.exe "$@"
```

`set -f` has no effect because the double-quoted argument array ( `"$@"` ) undergoes no further expansions.

If `"$@"` contains an argument whose value is `*`, it will get through to `mono app.exe` unchanged.

The problem is, that the shell  calling this wrapper script will want to expand the asterisk, as `set +f` is the default.

You'll need to `set -f` in this calling shell rather than in the wrapper.

---

With `set +f` (default), backslash (`\*`) is another alternative to quoting (`'*'` or `"*"`) that you might want to consider.

Comment: Thanks !
Are shells out there, wich are simpler ?? I started to hate bash. Waht about c-shell ? For my case, I would have to write three programs, instead of one. I shortly read an article from a shell-guru, what all could be made wrong. This was there long, that my consequence was: If nearly everything is wrong, then the sHELL must be wrong :-(
What about globally setting "-f" generally for my shell ?

Comment: `dash` is simpler, and you can pretty much learn it from its manpage. This globbing part is common to both, however. And yes, as I've already, mentioned, you can `set -f` in your interactive shell if you don't want globbing.

Comment: After starting to try different shells, I saw something similar in a ZSH discussion. This led me to:
>alias runit="set -f; runit"
So "runit *"
works perfectly for the moment.

Comment: Disabling globbing will cause more problems than it solves.  Unix programs generally don't expand wildcards themselves, they rely on the shell to do it for them (with globbing).  Using `dash` as an interactive shell is a terrible idea - it has none of the usability features like command-line history recall & editing.   BTW, if nearly everything seems wrong, it's most likely that there are one or more fundamental concepts that you haven't learnt yet - like the fact that wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by individual programs.  Learn the fundamentals and all will make sense.

Comment: Two more fundamental concepts are escaping and quoting.  If a character like `*` has a special meaning, you can "escape" or disable that special meaning with a backslash, e.g. `runit \*`.   Or with quotes, e.g. `runit '*'`

Comment: @cas Agreed. I wouldn't use dash interactively either, but I think learning dash is a good intro to shell scripting. Dash knowledge is usable in bash too, as dash is essentially the POSIX subset of bash.

Comment: I thought, I found a way around that, using 'alias'
`alias di='set -f; /ops/tools/di'`
But later, all shell expansion stops working, until I put the current session to the garbage. I thought, my 'set -f' inside an alias is local for each invocation? I looked into the BASHOPTS, but these are not changed.
Probably someone can give me a tip on that?

Comment: @mabra `flags=$-; set -f; .... ; set -$flags`. Alternatively, `set +f`.